# Difference between s = s + s and s += s with short

Tags: java, operators, short

I made a little test to manipulate a `short` and I came across a compilation problem.
The following code compile :

```
short s = 1;
s += s;
```

while this one doesn't :

```
short s = 1;
s = s + s; //Cannot convert from int to short
```

I've read that `shorts` are automatically promoted to `int`, but what's the difference between those two codes ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right that `short` are promoted to `ints`.  This occurs during the evaluation of the binary operator `+`, and it's known as *binary numeric promotion*.

However, this is effectively erased with compound assignment operators such as `+=`.  [Section 
15.26.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) states:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

That is, it's equivalent to casting back to `short`.

Comment: I liked your answer more than mine, than you got up-vote and i removed mine, Good Job.

Comment: @Patrick: There is another way in which compound assignment differs. Clearly `x *= y + z;` does not mean `x = x * y + z;` but rather `x = x * (y + z);`.  Well, the same is true of `+`. `x += y + z` means `x = x + (y + z)`, not `x = x + y + z`. The right-hand addition happens *before* the left-hand addition when you use `+=` in this manner. In algebra addition is associative and commutative, but computer math can violate these properties. The result of `x += y + z` need not be the same as `x = x + y + z`.